# docker standard_init_linux.go:228: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, shiny

I am struggling to find the cause of the following error after building an image and trying to run it. The error is bellow:

`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory`

the Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    xtail \
    wget \
    dos2unix
RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION- 
  amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb && \
    . /etc/environment && \
    R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='$MRAN')" && \
    cp -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/examples/* /srv/shiny-server/ && \
    chown shiny:shiny /var/lib/shiny-server

EXPOSE 3838

COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

the file shiny-server.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

if [ "$APPLICATION_LOGS_TO_STDOUT" != "false" ];
then
    # push the "real" application logs to stdout with xtail in detached mode
    exec xtail /var/log/shiny-server/ &
fi

# start shiny server
exec shiny-server 2>&1
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: What sort of file is `shiny-server.sh`?  If it's a shell script, does it start with a "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh`, and does it correctly have Unix line endings?

Comment: Also, make sure whatever is in its shebang line _actually exists_, and not only that the executable exists, but also that any shared libraries that executable links to exist (and, pertinently here, that the copy of `ld.so` it uses to link itself exists; you can get this error when mixing between glibc and musl libc, f/e, because they provide different dynamic linkers).

Comment: hello updated the question with the shiny-server.sh file

Comment: First guess is windows linefeeds in the script. There are quite a few other questions on the site with the other possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

correct the windows line endings with notepad++. That should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).